# Using Terms attribute to control selection of every item bar one

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm experimenting with the Sandwich Order sample that comes with a Bot Framework tutorial. In that example code, there is a `SandwichOrder` class that contains a list property to store toppings.

```
public enum ToppingOptions
{
    [Terms("except", "but", "not", "no", "all", "everything")]
    Everything = 1,

    Avocado, BananaPeppers, Cucumbers, GreenBellPeppers, Jalapenos,
    Lettuce, Olives, Pickles, RedOnion, Spinach, Tomatoes
}

[Serializable]
public class SandwichOrder
{
    [Prompt("Which {&} would you like? {||}")]
    [Describe("toppings")]
    public List<ToppingOptions> Toppings;

    public static IForm<SandwichOrder> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<SandwichOrder>()
            .Message("Welcome to the simple sandwich order bot!")
            .Build();
    }
};
```

I'm experimenting with the `Terms` attribute, as described here

[Advanced features of FormFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-advanced?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

When I run the bot in the emulator, the question to select the toppings appears as expected....

[image]

I enter my selection like so....

[image]

The result is not what I expected. The bot summarizes my selection like this...

[image]

According to the tutorial, the result should have been...

[image]

It's not clear to me where I've gone wrong here. Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I think you missed a part of the tutorial. You need to add code in the builder to handle the word 'everything' and 'but'.

The code below shows how to do for the word everything.

```
.Field(nameof(Toppings),
                validate: async (state, value) =>
                {
                    var values = ((List<object>)value).OfType<ToppingOptions>();
                    var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = values };
                    if (values != null && values.Contains(ToppingOptions.everything))
                    {
                        result.Value = (from ToppingOptions topping in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ToppingOptions))
                                        where topping != ToppingOptions.everything && !values.Contains(topping)
                                        select topping).ToList();

                        value = result.Value;
                    }
                    return result;
                })
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that. I jumped the gun without reading the example carefully, oops;